# Qt installer stuck

Tags: windows, qt, windows-7, installation

I'm running the *Qt Open Source* installer on Windows 7.

It's at 46% during the "Retrieving meta information from remote repository" step. It quickly got there and got stuck there 55 minutes already.

I tried restarting the installer and this time it got stuck again at the same step, but at 64%.

Any ideas?

*Notes:*

- The installer name is `qt-unified-windows-x86-2.0.3-1-online.exe`
- I believe the Qt version it's going to install is *Qt 5.7*, as that's the latest Qt version as of now
- I'm going to try the offline installer now

Comment: I haven't seen this myself. Is your network connection stable, maybe there's disconnection (and them some reconnection bug in the installer)? Or maybe it was a temporary server problem, or problem with your ISP, I suppose these are possible reasons. Anyway, unless it is for something like a single project, I'd try to get it done with the online installer, because you can get new versions and Qt Creator updates with it too.

Comment: I was having the same issue some time ago (few weeks). Just chose another distro (or options).

Comment: I advise to build Qt from source. You'll have way more control over what goes on, and you'll be able to do source-level debugging within Qt itself. The prerequisites are rather simple: MSVC 2015, python27 (not 3!), ruby, perl, with the latter 3 added to the path, and also add `<yourprefix>\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.0\gnuwin32\bin` to the path.

Comment: @QtRoS: What do you mean by another distro? And the only options provided by the installer are network proxy ones.

Comment: @hyde: Thanks, but my connection is stable. If all else fails, I'll try the online installer again tomorrow, ruling out server problems.

Comment: @StefanMonov - the online installer is slow (to download data) and unreliable, just get an offline installer, this way you can install the same download multiple times and even without internet connection. Alternatively, if you have MSYS2 you can get the build from its repo, although they are sometimes a little behind the latest version. I strongly reccomend MSYS2 thou, it is a great build environment for windows and a source for a ton of prebuilt libraries.

Comment: In case anyone else runs into this question due to the Qt installer hanging at a slightly different phase - in my case, `qtwebinstaller` - note that (at least the open-source installer) is pathetic in terms of feedback and it will literally seem to hang while it unzips a massive file. In my case, it seemed to hang on the noted package for a solid 20 minutes - no feedback whatsoever provided - but doing a file count on the associated folder in the file system revealed that, in fact, it was slowly unzipping the files there, and after all that time the installation resumed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that worked for me was to download and use the offline installer instead of the online one.

Comment: Well that is far from a solution. What if I need several versions of Qt?

Comment: @PredragManojlovic: Then I guess just DL several offline installers and install each one.

Comment: it is still a workaround due to huge overhead and making final development on several versions quite complicated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and added this as custom repo in the Maintenance Tool Settings - 
http://download.qt-project.org/online/qt5/windows/x86/online_repository/

After this it updated all the build-in repos and synced.

But I too really really think Qt should fix it, I have this problem every time on every machine.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably due to some network issues, as mentioned by some other users.
Just play around with your network and it should work.

In my case, I disconnected my WiFi and connected again and it worked.